# Is there a way to tell if a content owner has sanctioned another user's upload?

Tags: youtube-api

Apparently when a video is uploaded to youtube by someone who does not own the video content, the content owner, having found out, has the option to allow the video to remain up in exchange for profiting from its ads.

Is there a way of restricting feed results to include only those videos which the content owner has "ok'd" in that way?

I don't suppose either

```
<media:restriction type='country' relationship='deny'>DE etc</media:restriction>
```

or

```
<yt:state name='restricted' reasonCode='limitedSyndication'>
```

is any indication?

My goal is to make sure I don't have any links to illegally uploaded content on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the video is a [licenced content](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.licensedContent):

Indicates whether the video represents licensed content, which means that the content has been claimed by a YouTube content partner.

You can do so by doing [videos->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call via setting id=VIDEO_ID and in the response check if [contentDetails.licensedContent](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.licensedContent) set to True.

Comment: Sweet, looks like that is exactly the thing.  Thank you!

Comment: Apparently I don't have the rep to upvote but when I do, I will.  Thanks again.